# MySQL, identical alias and column name, which takes precedence?

Tags: mysql, sql

If MySQL encounters an identical column name and alias name, does one or the other always take precedence? e.g.

```
select NODE1 as `NODE2`, NODE2 as `NODE1` where `NODE2`=?
```

Would the above query always match the **column** NODE1 (**label** NODE2) with the placeholder? In other words, does the label always take precedence?

If so, is this true for all SQL databases?

Comment: you'll find that mysql is very forgiving in comparison to other databases, and allows many simple things that others absolutely forbid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use alias in `WHERE` clause, so column name will be important here.

> An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a
>   different name. **You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING
>   clauses to refer to the column:**

and

> **Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause.**
>   This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is
>   evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

Both quotes from [C.5.5.4. Problems with Column Aliases](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)